# Why break wind means fart?

Tags: understanding

As a non-English native speaker. I found it hard to understand why **break wind**  means fart.should I just remember the phrase and give up to try to understand why it means that.

Comment: Well, the word "break" has all the related literal and figurative meanings of having something and then break it. "Wind" means gas in your stomach. "Break wind" it is like breaking the gas, getting it out, farting. That's how I relate it in my mind.

Comment: It can also mean **burping**...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb [**break**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/break) in *break wind* means very close to its intransitive sense defined in Wiktionary:

> (intransitive) To burst forth; to make its way; to come into view.

The reason that the transitive usage is not defined in major dictionaries is it is rarely used that way. **Break wind** is an idiomatic expression where the noun [**wind**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wind) means [flatus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flatus):

> (uncountable) Gas generated in the digestive tract.

To [break wind](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+wind) literally means:

> To make one's flatus (gas) burst forth from one's anus or to **expel gas** from the anus

[Wiktionary, McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should give it up. **"Breaking wind"** is simply an idiomatic, descriptive euphemism for passing gas anally or "farting." If you think about it, it actually makes sense. Try looking it up online for more information about its origins and etymology.

Answer (score 1):

An ancient idea was that these intestinal gases were winds, and one of the old meanings of the verb **break** was 'to expel'.

*Þe jous of þis herbe put in mannys nesetherlys brekyth out reume oþer wycked fylthe.*